# How many different 5 cycles are there of 5 symbols

Tags: abstract-algebra

I try to calculate how many cycles there are of the form $(12345)\in S_5$. It is a little harder than  I thought. My first intuition was it must be $5!$, but I'm sure that I'm overcounting. How can I find out what the answer must be ? I would like to learn some kind of basic trick to solve those kind of problems. I always get confused by those counting problems as there seem so many different way to look at such a problem.

Comment: Hint: Two cycles correspond to the same permutation iff one can permute the elements of one cyclically to obtain the other (ie, move the first one to the back a suitable  number of times).

Comment: Hint (not that different from Tobias's yet given in a different form): since any 5-cycle in $\,S_5\,$ *must* contain 1, fix it as the first element of the cycle: how many options are you left with then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, it is tempting to think there are $5!$. But you will have counted each one several times. For example: $(12345) = (23451) = (34512) = (45123) = (51234)$. They all represent the cycle:

\begin{array}{ccccc}
& & 1 & & 
\\ &\nearrow & & \searrow \\
5 & & & & 2 & \\ \uparrow & & & & \downarrow \\
4 & & \longleftarrow & &3 
\end{array}
In fact, every five-cycle can be rearranged in five different ways; there are five starting points.

Hence, the answer is $5! \div 5 = 4! = 24$.

Comment: Why does my solution manual say 12 ? Maybe I'm interpreting the question incorrect. The real question was how many simple graphs are there of 5 vertices where every vertix has grade 2. I thought this must be equivalent to cycles of length 5 in $S_5$, but maybe not.

Comment: A graph is unoriented, while a cycle is oriented. There are no arrows in a graph. For example the cycle $(12345)$ is different to the cycle $(15432)$. But as graphs: 1 joins 2, which joins 3, which joins 4, which joins 5, which joins back to 1.

Comment: Aaaaaaah of course, thank you !

Comment: No problem. That's why there are twice as many cycles: there is a clockwise and an anti-clockwise version of each graph.

Answer (score 2):

Item $1$ has four choices of where to go.  Wherever you send it has three choices, as it cannot go to $1$, then each one has one less choice, so the answer is $4!=24$.  The argument is the same for general $n$, that there are $(n-1)!$ cycles.