# How many different 2-regular graphs are there with 5 vertices?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> How many different 2-regular (simple) graphs are there with 5 vertices?

I just asked a very similar question, and I actually already understand the answer of this question.

I think there are very much different ways to look at such a question (but maybe I'm wrong) and my head always kind of feel unsatisfied, even if I get the answer. I hope my head get a little more satisfied by actually understanding the different ways to solve this problem. I see this problem now like:

---

Just by trial and error I understand that the graph shoud look like:

\begin{array}{ccccc}
& & 1 & & 
\\ & ╱ & & ╲ \\
5 & & & & 2 & \\ | & & & & | \\
4 & & — & &3 
\end{array}

And as there are $4!$ cycles of the form $(12345)\in S_5$, there must be $4!/2$ graphs of this form as $(12345)$ and $(54321)$ are different cycles but represent the same graph.

---

So this is one way to look at this problem, but I'm interested in other ways to think of this question.

Comment: OK first you show that all 2-regular graphs with 5 vertices are cycles, then you should be able to count the number of cycles just like it was done in one of your previous questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385603/how-many-different-5-cycles-are-there-of-5-symbols

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First lets observe that any simple graph $G$ with $5$ vertices and $2$-regular must be connected.

Indeed, assuming that $G$ is disconnected, one component must have 2 or less vertices. But then no vertex in this component can have degree higher than  $2-1=1$.

Then $G$ must have a cycle, since it cannot be a tree. This cycle must have length 3,4 or 5. But this cycle cannot be connected to any other vertex, as the vertices of the cycle already have degree $2$. Thus the cycle is a component of $G$, and since $G$ is connected, it means that the cycle is $G$.

Thus $G$ is a cycle graph, hence $G$ is $C_5$.

As unlabeled graph $C_5$ is the only graph. If you look at labeled graphs, you need to label $C_5$ in all possible ways, and your counting is right: if you fix the vertex $\{1\}$ there are $4!$ ways to label the other vertices and you get each graph twice (clockwise and counterclockwise).

**P.S.** The argument i used in the third paragraph works more generally: If $G$ is **connected** and $2$-regular then $G$ is some $C_n$.

**P.P.S.** If $G$ is $2$-regular but not necessarily connected, then each component is $2$ regular and connected thus some $C_k$. This, together with the observation that $C_k$ must have at least 3 vertices can be used to clasify all simple $2$ regular graphs with $n$ vertices, for small $n$.

Comment: does this work for and number of vertices? Such as there can be 100! different graphs of 100 vertices?

Comment: @Rodolphe Yes, any two regular connected graph must be some $C_k$, you can prove this by induction on the number of edges (contract on edge for the inductive step). Thus if $G$ is a two regular graph, any component is two regular and connected, thus is some $C_k$. This proves that $G=C_{k_1}+..+C_{k_l}$.

Comment: @Rodolphe Classifying all graphs then reduces to finding all ways of writing $n=k_1+...+k_l$ with $l \geq 1$ and $k_i \geq 3$. This can be done easely, observe that $l \leq \frac{n}{3}$ and for each fixed $l$, by subtracting $2$ from each $k_i$ you need to write $n-2l$ as the sum of $l$ positive integers. This is, if I remember right a standard bars and stripes method.

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed only one $5$-vertex $2$-regular graph, which is isomorphic to the $5$-cycle:

[image: $5$-cycle]

This graph has the [dihedral group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group) (which I will denote $D_5$ today) as its automorphism group.

Let $A$ be the set of labelled graphs isomorphic to the $5$-cycle.  The symmetric group $S_5$ [acts on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) $A$ by permuting the vertex labels.  There is only one orbit under this group action, and this orbit is $A$.  The elements of $S_5$ that stabilise a labelled graph in $A$ are precisely the elements of $D_5$.  Hence, by the Orbit-Stabiliser Theorem $$|A|=\frac{|S_5|}{|D_5|}=\frac{5!}{10}.$$

In general, the same argument can be used to show that the number of labelled graphs isomorphic to a graph $G$ is $$\frac{|V(G)|!}{|\mathrm{Aut}(G)|}$$ where $V(G)$ is the set of vertices of $G$ and $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is the automorphism group of $G$.